# Can't Access Computer Configuration > Preferences or user configuration > Preferences

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, active-directory

After creating a new GPO in Windows Server 2008R2

- Right click Edit on the newly created GPO
  Group policy Management Editor opens
- Clicking on Preferences shows this popup error

[image]

After Clicking ok the preferences folder is blank. I tried on existing GPO's to see if i can access the Preferences and I was able to do so.

Followed this Kb here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294257 with no luck

All the fsmo roles are running fine, and trying this as an admin. Any tips appreciated

Comment: This also happens when I copy an existing GPO set the permission levels to the original permission or default permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the error message makes me think this computer is having trouble communicating with your DC for some reason. You can change the DC you're running against in GPMC (Right click on domain name in GPMC > Change domain controller). Give this a shot first.

Second, take a look at your event logs and see if there's any further information being logged.

Finally, this also sounds similar to the issue described in [Missing sections and settings in Group Policy editor](https://serverfault.com/questions/732251). Try uninstalling the Group Policy tools and reinstalling.

Comment: uninstalling the Group Policy tools and reinstalling did the trick