# Missing sections and settings in Group Policy editor

Tags: group-policy

I'm trying to edit an AD group policy that maps network drives.  The policy works fine, I can view the settings under the Settings tab and see the existing drive mappings, the structure in Sysvol is intact, but when I go to edit it in GPME the entire Users > Preferences section does not have any sections and settings underneath it -- it just says "There are no items to show in this view."  I also noticed the Computer Config Preferences section has the same problem.

I checked other GPOs and they have the same problem -- User Config > Preferences folder is there but nothing is underneath it.  [Missing Preferences settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMkEI.png)

I tried re-registering all the following components and that did not fix the problem.

- Administrative Templates and Scripts: gptext.dll
- Folder Redirection: fde.dll
- Internet Explorer Maintenance: ieaksie.dll
- IP Security: ipsecsnp.dll
- Public Key and Software Restriction: certmgr.dll
- Remote Installation Services: rigpsnap.dll
- Security: wsecedit.dll
- Software Installation: appmgr.dll

I created a new GPO, same issue.  Nothing under Preferences. I've asked four of my colleagues and they have no idea either.  I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this on my own by removing Group Policy Management from the list of installed Server Features, rebooting the server and reinstalling the GPM feature.

Comment: This did not work for me. My server is Windows Server 2012 R2. Even adding the GPM feature to a brand new Windows Server 2012 R2 machine did not show the necessary item. See screenshot: https://content.screencast.com/users/rpresser/folders/Jing/media/d57c5100-984c-4756-a1fb-58f5d0172b67/2017-12-21_1242.png