# Missing Remote Installation Services in GPO editor

Tags: group-policy

A colleague added some new settings to the Default Domain Policy GPO. I wanted them to live in their own GPO, so I copy/pasted the Default Domain Policy GPO and started removing all but what I wanted out of the new GPO.

There are settings relating to Remote Installation Services in this GPO, shown in the Settings view in Group Policy Management, that cannot be seen in the Group Policy Management Editor.

[image: Screenshot showing missing items in editor]

I have seen this question: [Missing sections and settings in Group Policy editor](https://serverfault.com/q/732251/190386)
The answer given there does not work for me. Even adding the GPM feature to a brand new Windows Server 2012 R2 does not fix it.

It probably does not hurt anything for me to leave those features in this GPO. I do not intend to change them, and they are the same as in the Default Domain Policy GPO. (In fact I never intend to use RIS at all.) Still, it is a little aggravating to have these non-editable settings in my GPO. Any ideas?

Comment: Being RIS a deprecated technology (WDS replaced it in 2008), I would say you may need to download and install the old GPO templates from 2003 or 2008.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete it manually from the GPO:

Go to `C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\USER\Microsoft` (the GUID is the same on all systems, it is the Default Domain Policy) and delete the folder `Remote Installation`. Refresh your GPO settings editor afterwards and RIS will be gone.